# How to use TortoiseSVN together with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

I want to use TortoiseSVN together with Eclipse.
For now I just want to try it out.
So I use a local folder as repository.
I have installed TortoiseSVN 1.7.13.
I created a folder called 'REPOSITORY' and chose 'Create repository here' from
the context menu.

As other websites told, I installed Subclipse 1.8.22 in Eclipse.
I use the SVNKit1.7.9 as client or connector (Whatever it is called).

I had already some projects in eclipse's workspace.
From the context menu I chose 'Team->Share Project'.

That is what other websites told to do.

It did show the normal commit dialog and so on.
The projects are marked as commited but the folder 'REPOSITORY'
is still small in size.

It seems, that the projects where not copied or moved to the repository.

At work we have a server based SVN. I just want to have something like that at home.

Did I miss something?
Isn't it the purpose of the SVN repository to hold a copy of the projects?
So the commited projects should be inside the REPOSITORY, right?

Greetings

Mike

Comment: i guess you created a copy of the projects in your workspace wehen you imported them

Comment: Yes, some projects where imported into the workspace and one is newly created. Does this have anything to do with the SVN? I installed TortoiseSVN AFTER I setup a newly downloaded Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you have to manually import the project in Eclipse into the repository created with TortoiseSVN before actually committing to it.

This [other page](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aHhk9FUn_HOgJ%3awww.timashworth.co.uk/page/6/) might help you. It gives a very detailed walkthrough of how to set up exactly the kind of local system you want. In essence:

1. In Eclipse, **delete the project but not its contents** (`Delete project contents on disk` unchecked). This will leave the project's folder under your workspace location untouched.
2. Outside Eclipse, **import the project folder into the repository** previously created with TortoiseSVN (`Right click on folder` >  `TortoiseSVN` > `Import` and select the URL of the repository). Once imported, you may wish to delete the project folder.
3. Back in Eclipse, **checkout the project from TortoiseSVN's repository** (e.g. `Right click on Package Explorer` > `Import..` > `SVN` > `Projects from SVN`).

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1817612 Thanks for accepting the answer. I've edited it since the linked page seems to be down now.

Answer (score 1):

If your project's folder structure and package structure are the same, you can use [Eclipse Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/). It's just a plugin for eclipse and provides all features of TortoiseSVN